# Heroku: No Redis instances found

Tags: heroku, redis

I want to change the maxmemory settings of Redis for my Heroku app, following [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#maxmemory-policy).

Unfortunately, when I do `heroku redis:maxmemory angelfish-9042 --policy volatile-lru`, I get the following response in the terminal:

> No Redis instances found.

I have the Redis addon running and the Redis plugin installed.

Any idea how to change the maxmemory settings? (I hit the limit allowed)

Comment: What is the output from `heroku redis:info`? Please [edit] your question and add that information. If you select the text after you paste it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button it will be formatted as code.

Comment: It seems it worked even if the output is "No Redis instances found.", thanks!

Comment: That's not what I expected; I really wanted to look at the output of the command. I'm curious about your app name. Normally automatically-generated app names on Heroku have _three_ components, not two. For example, I'd expect your app to be called something like `angel-fish-9042` or `angelfish-snowball-9042`.

Comment: Curiously, there is no output when I run `heroku redis:info`